# Five questions in one. All subjective

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, low-quality-posts, opinion-based

I'm guessing (and hoping) that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589235/cms-vs-do-it-yourself) will eventually undergo a review. It's five subjective questions bundled into one question from a relatively new user. I saw it yesterday and voted to close it as opinion-based, but no one else has voted on it.

I was also surprised that a very high rep user actually answered the question. I have to assume that the intention was to help the person asking the question, however wouldn't an explanation as to why this type of question isn't a fit for SO have been a better idea, while also explaining that a question shouldn't contain four other questions? Are we encouraging users to post subjective, multi-point questions by answering them?

Comment: High rep users will answer anything you put in front of them. It's how they got the high rep

Comment: @random [so very true](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244261/what-is-people-helped-and-why-does-it-exist-at-all#comment798506_244290)